# Android Studio - Select image from gallery

Tags: android, android-studio

On the app I want a message or dialog box to appear when I select the camera on the top right corner. Once camera is selected I want a message to appear to say either 'Take photo' or 'Select from Gallery'

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!contact.getHidden()) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.conversation, menu);
        if (!Preferences.getBoolean(this, Preferences.PREF_DEV_IMAGE_CAPTURE, false)) {
            MenuItem camera = menu.findItem(R.id.launch_camera);
            camera.setVisible(false);

        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.launch_voip_call) {
        Utils.startCall(this, contact);
        return true;
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.launch_camera) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(ConversationActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
        cameraIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_CONTACT_JID", contact.getJid());
        startActivity(cameraIntent);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: very new to android studio, as I only have basic knowledge. Just wondering how I would get a dialogue box to appear with two options when the FAB is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your strings.xml add

```
<array name="image_upload_methods">
    <item>Take photo</item>
    <item>Select from Gallery</item>
</array>
```

When user clicks the launch_camera

```
else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.launch_camera) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setTitle("Upload Demo")
                            .setItems(R.array.image_upload_methods, new OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    if (which == 0){
                                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(ConversationActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
                                        cameraIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_CONTACT_JID", contact.getJid());
                                        startActivity(cameraIntent);
                                    }else {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                                        intent.setType("image/*");
                                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                                                "Select Picture"), RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
                                    }
                                }
                            }).show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try this.

Comment: the java code AlertDialog.Builder should be placed inside your onOptionsItemSelected, just as you have shown. The<array> should be inside /app/values/string.xml

Comment: Feel free to ask any doubts

Comment: Now how would I go about if I wanted to select an image from the gallery and send it to a contact?

Comment: Go through this http://codetheory.in/android-pick-select-image-from-gallery-with-intents/

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Pick Image from")
   .setCancelable(false)
   .setPositiveButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
           //camera intent
       }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //gallery intent
       }
   });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```